# Error on unexpected bracket in gawk

Tags: awk, makefile, flex-lexer

I am trying to create a DiffMerge like app that will show me differences between Rhapsody diagrams more friendly.

I did some research and I found out that someone did a `.sbs` to `.xml` file convertor[1], which then can be parsed easily.

Now, when I try to compile the file using `make all` I get this error:

```
flex lexer.l
gawk "/#define YY_BUF_SIZE/{gsub(/16384/, "(1024*1024)")};{print}" lex.yy.c > lex.yy.c.new
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [flex] Error 2
```

Could you help me solve this?

The files I used are on the Git link below.

Note: I commented the line with `SHELL=...` from Makefile because I'm working in Linux.

[1] https://github.com/PrzemekWirkus/sbs2xml-conv

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you reproduce this error by manually executing the command, i.e., run `gawk "/#define YY_BUF_SIZE/{gsub(/16384/, "(1024*1024)")};{print}" lex.yy.c > lex.yy.c.new`  in your terminal?

Comment: Also, it's best to format your code snippets, and errors, too. This drastically improves readability of your questions.

Comment: In the Makefile, modify the recipe that contains the `gawk` command (line 38): replace the outer `"` by simple quotes (`gawk '/#define...{print}' ...`). And please report the bug (open an issue) to let the author know.

Comment: Thank you both for the welcome and the quick responses.
@lubgr, I ran just the command with gawk, the output was the same error.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I did replace the " " with ' ', the error about the bracket is gone, there a lot of warnings about some functions from the stdio.h and string.h libraries that were generated with underscore '_' from flex. Now it generates an executable. Thanks a lot, to both of you. As soon as I will be able to use the .exe file, I will post this on the author's Git page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `"`s around the script to `'`s (which they **always** should be anyway):

```
gawk '/#define YY_BUF_SIZE/{gsub(/16384/, "(1024*1024)")};{print}' lex.yy.c > lex.yy.c.new
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this and then solved some minor errors and it worked from the files that flex generates .c files